# Put values from a jsontext column into individual columns

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a view that contains 3 columns (MID, Titles, ModDate).  The Titles column is filled with json.  The data looks like this:

```
MID column value example: 1
Titles column value example:  
[{sequence: "2", IDnumber: "1349709", name: "TEST", empid: "197081", Document: "",cindicator: "C", cleardate: "1983-02-23",}, 
{sequence: "1", IDnumber: "9949709", name: "TEST 2", empid: "197080", Document: "",cindicator: "C", cleardate: "1983-02-23"}]
ModDate column value example:  1983-02-23
```

Notice that the column named 'titles' contains several arrays? separated by a comma.  The field names are:  sequence, IDnumber, name, empid, Document, cindicator, cleardate.

I want to view some of these fields in the 'titles' column as individual columns in my result set.
For example:  I want the results to display the following columns:  MID, sequence, IDNumber, name,   ModDate

I tried this query:

```
select MID, 
JSON_VALUE(titles, '$.sequence') sequence
JSON_VALUE(titles, '$.IDnumber') IDNumber,
JSON_VALUE(titles, '$.name') Name, ModDate
from table1
```

It will display the individual columns that I want but the fields from the titles column are all null values.  I checked that I spelled them correctly and the case matches.  I also tried adding quotes: `JSON_VALUE(titles, '$."sequence"')` sequence.  Same thing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `OPENJSON()` call and an `APPLY` operator:

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES (
   1, 
   '[
   {
      "sequence":"2",
      "IDnumber":"1349709",
      "name":"TEST",
      "empid":"197081",
      "Document":"",
      "cindicator":"C",
      "cleardate":"1983-02-23"
   },
   {
      "sequence":"1",
      "IDnumber":"9949709",
      "name":"TEST 2",
      "empid":"197080",
      "Document":"",
      "cindicator":"C",
      "cleardate":"1983-02-23"
   }
   ]', 
   '19830223'
)) v ([Mid], [Titles], [ModDate])
```

Statement:

```
SELECT d.ModDate, d.Mid, j.*
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON (d.Titles) WITH (
   sequence varchar(2) '$.sequence',
   IDnumber varchar(7) '$.IDnumber',
   name varchar(50) '$.name',
   empid varchar(6) '$.empid',
   Documnet varchar(50) '$.Document',
   cindicator varchar(1) '$.cindicator',
   cleardate varchar(10) '$.cleardate'
 ) j
```

Result:

```
ModDate   Mid sequence IDnumber name   empid  Documnet cindicator cleardate
19830223  1   2        1349709  TEST   197081          C          1983-02-23
19830223  1   1        9949709  TEST 2 197080          C          1983-02-23
```

Comment: Thank you!  I am trying to make this work now

Comment: @KatIsenberg To elaborate, you have an array which you need to break out with `OPENJSON`, if it was a single object then your original code would have worked